# Sublime Text Go To Folder Shortcut

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am familiar with sublime text's `Ctrl+P` to navigate between files, but is there any command or plugin to navigate between folders (Highlight them in the sidebar) and perform actions on them there?

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you see this working? What is the scope you want to find the fie in? The project? Something else? When you have found this folder what do you expect to have happen? Open all the files in the folder? Highlight it in the sidebar? Something else?

Comment: Highlight it in the side bar so I can perform actions on it there.

Answer (score 5):

The shortcut for moving to the sidebar nav is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will bring you back to the file you're editing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Project` ⇢ `Add Folder To Project...` from the menu or you can bind the command to a key to use it more easily.
The command for this action is `prompt_add_folder`.

When you add the folder you want to your project you can do actions on folders like `New Folder` , `New File`, `Remove Folder from Project` and other commands depending on other plugins you may have installed.

[image]